# (Visual Studio) Lot of linker errors when trying to link microsoft libraries statically with SFML libs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static, linker, sfml

So i need an indiot-proof app.
I have it done, but when i try to run it inside a bare windows 7 virtual machine i have a lot of errors like msvcp140.dll is missing etc. etc.
so i was searching google in order to statically link those.
I found that i should change it in project code generation options, so I did.
I also have SFML linked statically.
The problem is i get a lot of linker errors refering to SFML like:

```
sfml-system-s.lib(String.cpp.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in main.obj
```

Im not sure why is it happening, so i ask for help here

Comment: The simplest way would be just compiling it with another compiler (see the instructions on SFML's website), so that you don't need those microsoft libraries that Visual Studio's compiler requires. Or just include those .dlls with your application, assuming you're not limited just to your executable.

Comment: @Noctiphobia the problem is i need to use visual studio because my app uses both SFML and winapi (winapi is used to define how sfml window looks here)
so i need to use visual studio
now i just think ill recompile sfml using cmake but i have a compiler not found anc cxx compiler not found, im not sure why but i will try to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was pretty sure I had your problem figured out just by reading the error message, thinking about the term "RuntimeLibrary", and how it was saying that there was a mismatch between "DynamicRelease" and "StaticRelease". My intuition said that you were trying to combine a library that was compiled targeting one version of the CRT with an application that was targeting a different version of the CRT. Given that "MD" and "MT" are compiler switches that control whether you are dynamically or statically linking the run-time, respectively, that's a pretty good clue, too.

But just to be sure, I took the actual error code (LNK2038) and looked it up in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj889284.aspx). Sure enough, it contains a passage that describes the problem exactly:

> **RuntimeLibrary**
>
> Indicates the version of the C++ Standard Library and C runtime that's used by an app or library. Code that uses one version of the C++ Standard Library or C runtime is incompatible with code that uses a different version. For more information, see [/MD, /MT, /LD (Use Run-Time Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx).

The linker has gotten smart over the years. It is trying to protect you from making a serious mistake. All modules that are being linked together need to have been compiled to target the same type of run-time library. If you want the app to link statically to the CRT (/MT), you need to make the library link statically as well (/MT).
Project properties → Configuration Properties → C/C++ → Code Generation → Runtime Library.
Don't forget to Rebuild All.

Comment: Im not sure what should i do, the explanation is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: In  Project properties → Configuration Properties → C/C++ → Code Generation → Runtime Library i have /mt checked and i use static version of sfml as well

Comment: You have to change the way the *library* is compiled, not just the app. That's the point about their having to match.