# How to make FetchContent always build in release mode

Tags: cmake

I am using `FetchContent` like below. How do I make fetched `Catch2` library always build in Release mode regardless of whether my build is invoked as `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug ..` ?

```
Include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    Catch2
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git
    GIT_TAG v3.4.0
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Catch2)
```

Comment: FetchContent makes the external project's `CMakeLists.txt` to be **part of your project**, so it **shares** the build type with your main project. Well, you may assign different value to `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable before calling `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` (which is effectively `add_subdirectory` call), but you may got many surprises with such setup. And with multiconfiguration generators (like Visual Studio) the variable `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using FetchContent like below. How do I make fetched Catch2 library always build in Release mode regardless of whether my build is invoked as cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug .. ?

You can't. FetchContent calls `add_subdirectory` under the hood. Which effectively makes Catch2 part of your project. You can't just make part of your project debug/release.

Mixing/matching debug/release libraries can be problematic depending on your platform. MSVC in particular [will produce linker errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753104/visual-studio-lot-of-linker-errors-when-trying-to-link-microsoft-libraries-sta).

To quote MSVC directly:

> All modules passed to a given invocation of the linker must have been compiled with the same run-time library compiler option (/MD, /MT, /LD).

Meaning if one library is compiled with `/MT` and another with `/MTd` it will fail.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.140)